# Formating the Data obtained after scraping url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to scrape two urls https://www.ncco.org/2021-season/set-ii-call-of-destiny and https://msorchestra.com/event/41st-annual-pepsi-pops-a-blast-in-the-park-3/ using the following code.

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.parse
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import os

service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--incognito')

URL = "https://msorchestra.com/event/41st-annual-pepsi-pops-a-blast-in-the-park-3/"

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

for h in soup.find_all('header'):
    try:
        h.extract()
    except:
        pass
for f in soup.find_all('footer'):
    try:
        f.extract()
    except:
        pass

text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')


print(text)
```

The printed text format is different for both the urls. https://www.ncco.org/2021-season/set-ii-call-of-destiny  gives a more readable format but https://msorchestra.com/event/41st-annual-pepsi-pops-a-blast-in-the-park-3/  gives a grouped together format which makes it difficult to read. How is it possible to make the format ofhttps://msorchestra.com/event/41st-annual-pepsi-pops-a-blast-in-the-park-3/  similar to https://www.ncco.org/2021-season/set-ii-call-of-destiny

Answer (score 0):

We can obtain the same result by adding new line character `'\n'` at the end.

```
text = soup.getText(separator=u'\n')
```